# Hash redundancy

Tags: php, hash, md5, sha1

I have a generic but technic question:

- Is that the hash algorithms (MD5, SHA1...) are designed to not be redundant as long as they receive a certain number of characters?
- If there are, how can I find this 'no redundancy' limit?

For example:

- [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com) service uses the `mail` to generate an `id` as: `id = md5(mail)`
- If two strings which have less of a certain number of characters can have a same hash, I suppose that is not a good practice because conflicts can appears?

I know that statistically the risk is extremely low, but this is not enough according to me.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why is it not enough? You're talking about 2^(bits in the hash) number of possible options.

Comment: Yes you are right, but how do you know if two strings of less than 50 characters (for exemple) can not have the same hash in spite of the number of combinations?

Comment: You test all of them. Keep in mind that in order to find two blocks that come down to the same hash, TEAMS OF SCIENTISTS go looking for these collisions, and they publish entire papers on them. It's not going to come up randomly; that's what these hashing functions are designed for in the first place.

Comment: OK, I understand that it is almost impossible to have a collision between hashes of two simple email addresses. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If the strings are less than the hash length, and different then by definition, they will have different hashes. For example, pad the strings to the same length and just take the bits of the strings and 'mess them up a bit'.  You can only have 'collisions' on strings that are longer than than hash length. The approach is to try and get every bit in the input string to affect every bit in the 'hash' string in some way.

Comment: Clear and helpful response, thank for that!